# Should the testing interface always be identical to the functional interface?

Tags: java, testing, tdd, mockito, subclass

TDD newb here.  I know we "test the interface not the implementation", but might there be a case for having a "testing interface" of class X, using a **Subclass Mock** and protected methods, which could be a superset of the functional interface defined by the public methods of class X?

Say I have a class like this:

```
class IndexManager {
    IndexManager( File file ){
        ...
    }

    public void someFunctionalMethodUsedByOtherClasses(){
         ...
    }

}
```

In my test class I go like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class IndexManagerTest {
    ...

    class SubclassMockIndexManager extends IndexManager {
        SubclassMockIndexManager( File file ){
            super( file );
        }

        @Override
        protected IndexWriterConfig createIndexWriterConfig( Analyzer analyser ){
            return super.createIndexWriterConfig( analyser );
        }

    }

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    SubclassMockIndexManager injectedSpySM_IndexMgr = new SubclassMockIndexManager(tempFile);
```

And make a method in it to test the "non-public interface" (AKA "testing interface"):

```
@Test
public void whenIndexIsMadeAnIndexWriterConfigShouldBeCreated() throws Exception {
    injectedSpySM_IndexMgr.makeIndexForFile();
    verify( injectedSpySM_IndexMgr ).createIndexWriterConfig(  mock(Analyzer.class) );
}
```

In response, to turn red to green, I respond by modifying my app class as follows:

```
class IndexManager {
    IndexManager( File file ){
        ...
    }

    // added as part of normal red-green TDD development cycle
    protected IndexWriterConfig createIndexWriterConfig( Analyzer analyser ){
        ... // make IndexWriterConfig object

        return indexWriterConfig;
    }

    public void someFunctionalMethodUsedByOtherClasses(){
         ...
    }

}
```

It's just that I'm puzzled why the TDD development cycle should ***necessarily*** be confined to testing methods which are exposed to all other classes...

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a `functionA` and its formed of `functionB` and `functionC`

It would be a waste of time to test both `functionB` & `functionC`, when you can only test the end result ie `functionA`...As long as `functionA` passes the test then there is no need to test the others.

The `functionA` in my example is similar to that of testing an interface.

Or in laymen's terms: It's like as long as water is coming out of 'the end of the pipe' to the exact you expect then there is no need for you to be testing the flow of the water for every 2 feets.

Though it is still up to you to make the decisions

### EDIT

To avoid writing tests for `functionB` & `functionC` it's best to write `test_functionA` first and once it's green you go from there. Likely your `test_functionB` & `test_functionC` would never be needed. Writing `testfunctionC` & `testfuncionB` would make it more difficult and would make you need to write all three tests.

Comment: Thanks... this is what I might call the "purist TDD" answer.  And there is clearly a big philosophical commitment in this "school" to the idea that the internal operations of a class are "irrelevant".  For a TDD newb like me the problem is the other "weighty TDD directive": never write a line of code without a test.  I currently find that there is often a tension between these two fundamental TDD rules!

Comment: @mikerodent Valid point. I *totally* get it. I *think* you are following a tutorial or something. And perhaps the person is teaching how to test everything *only* to teach you. Not for sake of actually doing it in a real project. But if not: The two you mentioned don't necessarily counter one another. I mean in that approach you can never test everything. It becomes cumbersome and laboring. There is a point where you must *selectively* do tests.

Comment: @mikerodent I recommend taking a look into [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M) video. It may not suit you 100%, but it's good in building a TDD mindset:)

Comment: @mikerodent Actually I'm learning from [this](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/test-driven-ios-development-swift) book :) ...anyhow as a workaround you could first write test_functionA and that would suffice for you to not write any tests_functionB or test_functionC. Because you *are* GREEN. However if you write test_functionB or test_FunctionC then you have to do write all 3.

Comment: Watched... useful: gradually I inch towards greater enlightenment. But I have already, as you rightly surmise, read a few books.  From a hands-on PoV the best one so far has probably been "Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests".  One of possibly many newb errors I'm committing may be making my app classes shoulder too many responsibilities.  Splitting into smaller classes forces public visibility on more methods (in fact often package-private would suffice, but creating test classes with that visibility constrains your test directory structure...).

Comment: @mikerodent Good luck. I kinda shared all my knowledge. I'm also learning TDD. I think writing modular ie not leaking a classes responsibility is important. I think the rest comes with experience and sitting next to a senior developer.

Comment: @mikerodent I forgot to say, you splitting your functions into smaller classes is good. But you didn't address the comment I made about writing test_functionA first. Because if you do that, then wherever you other functions are you still don't need to do anything assuming you are still GREEN. Remember whenever you add new functions just make try to fail your test to be sure it is failing where it needs to fail...

Comment: Sorry, no, I understand the principle fully.  It's just that I want to spin a constraining web of tests around my class that goes somewhat beyond its requisite public ("functional") interface.